# Am I counting the array comparisons correctly in this script?

Tags: python, arrays, numbers

I have this script below that finds the smallest and largest values in an integer array. The goal is to complete this task in less than *1.5 x N* comparisons, where *N* is the length of the input array, **n_list**. I want to ask a couple of questions.

1: (Inside the *for* loop) Is comparing the variables *smallest* or *largest* to *n* considered an array comparison? In the script below, I am counting it as one. If it is, why is this the case? The definition I was able to find said that an array comparison is between two arrays, and that's not really what I'm doing, IMO.

2: If I am not counting correctly, what am I doing wrong?

3: What would be a better approach to this problem?

Thanks so much, hope you're having a good day/night :)

```
 def findExtremes(n_list):

   smallest = n_list[0]
   largest = n_list[0]
   counter = 2 # See above

   for n in n_list:
      if n > largest:
         largest = n
         counter += 1
         continue
      elif n < smallest:
         smallest = n
         counter += 1
         continue
      else:
         counter += 1
         continue

   return(counter)
```

Comment: Your task says 1.5 * N comparisons, then in question one you say 'array comparisons'.  From the first statement I would say that it is total number of comparisons between any two integers, and that you haven't performed any comparisons until you start the for loop.

Comment: There's no such thing as "array comparison". Your function only has one array, so there isn't even another array to compare it with.

Comment: Actually, you need counter += 2, you have already done two comparisons.  Also should have counter += 2 in the elif.

Comment: Just as an aside... the continues are redundant in your for loop, because the entire body of the loop is an if..elif...else and only one body will execute (no code is skipped by the continue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only counting comparisons that succeed.

When the first `if` succeeds, you've done one comparison, and you correctly do `counter += 1`.

But if you get into the `elif`, you've done *two* comparisons: `n > largest` and `n < largest`, so you need to do `counter += 2`.

And if that comparison fails, you've still already done two comparisons, so you need to do `counter += 2` in the `else` block as well.

You don't need to initialize `counter = 2` at the beginning, you should set it to `0`. You'll count the two comparisons with the first element of the list in the loop.

Actually, you might want to just skip those elements, since the result is known. You can do:

```
for n in n_list[1:]:
```

to skip over them. If you're supposed to count these unnecessary comparisons, then it makes sense to initialize `counter = 2`.

Your question about "array comparisons" doesn't seem to be relevant at all. There's nothing about comparing arrays in this problem, you're just comparing array elements to other elements of the same array.

Your algorithm performs anywhere from N+1 to 2*N comparisons. The best case is when the array is sorted from smallest to largest -- the test that updates `largest` succeeds for each element, so it never has to update `smallest`. The worst case is when it's sorted in the reverse order or all the numbers are the same: all the `largest` tests fail, so it has to test each element to see if it's the new `smallest`. On average with random data it tends to be close to the worst case, about 1.95*N.

Comment: I originally had the `n_list[1:]`, due to setting the `smallest` and `largest` to the first element's value. I took it out by mistake.

I understand what you're saying about the array elements. Thank you for the answer; I'll make it more efficient, hopefully.